# how to add x̄= 17 label in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, label

I figured out how to add x̄ in ggplot labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= "bar(x)"), parse= TRUE)
```

But what I need to do is to label something like x̄= 17. Unfortunately, `geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= "bar(x)= 17"), parse= TRUE)` does not work because the `=` gets parsed, too. What I was able to do so far is this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= "bar(x)"), parse= TRUE) +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5.3, y= 5, label= "=17")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0, 10))
```

[image]

This does look as expected but the problem is that I work with different data, having different scales and some of my plots use `facet_grid()`. Thus, in my plots `x̄` and `=17` drift apart sometimes. Something like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= "bar(x)"), parse= TRUE) +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5.3, y= 5, label= "=17")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(5, 6))
```

How to properly add a x̄= 17 label in ggplot? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `label=paste("bar(x)=17")` ?

Comment: @YacineHajji for me `ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= paste("bar(x)=17")), parse= TRUE)` does not work

Comment: Yes this is very weird, I have the same issue as you. And couldn't find the unicode equivalent

Comment: The unicode bar is `\u0305`, which is placed after the glyph you'd want under the bar, so the label would be `"x\u0305 = 17"`

Comment: @teunbrand Could you post as answer? WIll accept. The only answer for now is way more complicated than simply `"x\u0305= 17"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
install.packages('latex2exp')
library(latex2exp)
ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= TeX(r'($\bar{x} = 17$)', output = "character")), size= 10, parse = TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

Credit to [this](https://uliniemann.com/blog/2022-02-21-math-annotations-in-ggplot2-with-latex2exp/) blog post for giving me a refresher on embedding LaTeX within ggplot plots

Answer (score 2):

You need to double the `=` to have it display as a single one, i.e.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_text(mapping= aes(x= 5, y= 5, label= "bar(x) == 17"), parse= TRUE, size = 10) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0, 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can read about the language used in parsed labels in the `?plotmath` help topic, and see examples by running `demo(plotmath)`.